# Use of log4j2 core package vs log4j2 api

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to migrate to log4j 2.x (2.6 exactly) from log4j 1.x. I see that methods like Logger.setLevel() is not available in org.apache.log4j.Logger (log4j-api package) but is available in org.apache.log4j.core.Logger (log4j-core package).

So basically I am forced to use core classes. It there anything wrong with that ? or is there something that I am overlooking ?

Comment: Why do you need `setLevel()`? Log4J is supposed to be configured from text files (XML). Anyway, see this page: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html

Comment: @Andreas It is to allow changing of log levels over JMX. That was how it is done using log4j 1.x   Is there any better way to do that in 2.x ?

Comment: Why cant you use something like 
`<Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Root>`
In your log4j2.xml ?
You can also use different configs like that

Comment: Better yet, why not use Log4j's built in JMX support?

Comment: @rgoers they don't allow us to change the configuration. do they ?

Comment: Log4j 2 lets you replace the configuration via JMX. Take a look at the log4j-JMX-gui component & the Log4j 2 JMX manual page.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Thanks. I will look more into that.

Comment: LoggerConfigAdminMBean has a setLevel method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/) related to setLevel method of log4j2 core - "This method is not exposed through the public API and is provided primarily for unit testing."

And from log4j2 [website](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) - "Note that unlike Log4j 1.x, the public Log4j 2 API does not expose methods to add, modify or remove appenders and filters or manipulate the configuration in any way."

& found a way to change log level here in log4j2 website [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#reconfig_level_from_code) page. still used core package but seems like its the correct way to do it.

```
// org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

Configurator.setLevel("com.example.Foo", Level.DEBUG);

// You can also set the root logger:
Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```